# Projection Matrix $I-A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I Don't really understand.. please help me.
Suppose $A$ is a projection matrix on the plane $U$. For which plane is $I-A$ a projection matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$I-A$ is a projection on the null space of $A$, i.e. the space of vectors $x$ such that $Ax=0$.  If this is in $3$ dimensions and $U$ is a $2$-dimensional plane, then $I-A$ is a projection on a line, not a plane.

Comment: sorry, yes it's a line and I forgot to mention A is 2X2 matrix.
So the question need to be " For which line..."